# Problems while parsing a nested json/list in python3?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I have a very large list `alist` which has a dict and a nested list like this:

```
a_list = [{'A': [], 's': {'code': '0', 'credits': '0', 'msg': 'OK'}},
 {'A': [{'dictionary': 'True',
    'item': 'pineapples',
    'id': '13',
    'score': '9.7899',
    'rollup': {'True': 'OK', 'Fiz': 'Yes'},
    'variant_list': [{'endp': '8', 'form': 'pineapple', 'register': '0'}]}], 'status': {'codecheck': '0', 'cred': '90809890', 'msg': 'OK'}},
......

{'A': [], 's': {'code': '0', 'credits': '0', 'msg': 'OK'}},
    ]
```

**How can I extract the extract the `item` parameter if and only if exist into a list like this:**

```
['NaN', 'pineapples', 'NaN']
```

I do not understand how to parse it since it has a very nested structure, the main issue which I am struggling with is to accessing to each element of the list and then to the other list and leaving a `NaN` string.

Comment: what doesn mean *and leaving a NaN string* ?

Comment: what do you mean by if it exists in a string?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thanks for the help!, as you can see in the first and the third element of  `a_list` they have just an empty list `{'A': [], 's': {'code': '0', 'credits': '0', 'msg': 'OK'}}` I would like to impute a `NaN` there, since it has a void list.

Comment: @tooty44, yes for instance just replace this `{'A': [], 's': {'code': '0', 'credits': '0', 'msg': 'OK'}},` for `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach(*list comprehension*):

```
a_list = [{'A': [], 's': {'code': '0', 'credits': '0', 'msg': 'OK'}},
          {'A': [{'dictionary': 'True',
                  'item': 'pineapples',
                  'id': '13',
                  'score': '9.7899',
                  'rollup': {'True': 'OK', 'Fiz': 'Yes'},
                  'variant_list': [{'endp': '8', 'form': 'pineapple', 'register': '0'}]}],
           'status': {'codecheck': '0', 'cred': '90809890', 'msg': 'OK'}},
          {'A': [], 's': {'code': '0', 'credits': '0', 'msg': 'OK'}},
          ]

result = ['NaN' if not len(o['A']) else o['A'][0]['item'] for o in a_list]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['NaN', 'pineapples', 'NaN']
```

---

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common
>   applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of
>   some operations applied to each member of another sequence or
>   iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a
>   certain condition.

*a certain condition*, in your case, is `'NaN' if not len(o['A']) else o['A'][0]['item']`

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Could you provide some explanation?.. I didnot understood pretty well the list comprehension.